# How can I use Javascript dynamic properties so Foo.Bar returns current Date()?

Tags: javascript

I want to create an object property that re-calculates it's value each time it is called.

I took at stab at it:

```
var Foo = { Bar : (function() { return Date(); })() }

alert(Foo.Bar); // shows time at object literal Foo was init'd
                // but need it to show time when it's called
```

It it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible - JS properties are not "executable" like C# properties are. The best you can do is a normal method.

Aside: from a design standpoint I would actual consider a self-changing property to be pretty poor. The principle of least surprise would be better served by a method anyway.

Comment: I agree... a function such as GetCurrentDate() would be more intuitive. +1

Comment: That was a contrived example but I also agree. In my scenario I really would like properties but I'll omit the details here for brevity.